# Assert two dataframes are not equal for Pytest

Tags: dataframe, try-catch, pytest, assert

I looked at another persons question that was out and i am trying to ask more based off of that,  i am trying to figure out why this is not working

```
 **@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input_1, expected_outcome",
   [
       (diag_config["clinical_input"]["code_tbl"],
        init_cohorts.get_clinical_code(diag_config["clinical_input"]["code_tbl"]))

   ])  def test_get_clinical_code_fail(test_input_1, expected_outcome):
try:
    result = init_cohorts.get_clinical_code(test_input_1)
    expected_outcome = init_cohorts.get_clinical_code(diag_config["clinical_input"]["prov_tbl"])
    pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(result.toPandas(), expected_outcome.toPandas())
except AssertionError:
    # frames are not equal
    pass
else:
    # frames are equal
    raise AssertionError**
```

what i  based this off of was this

```
def assert_frame_not_equal(*args, **kwargs):
try:
    assert_frame_equal(*args, **kwargs)
except AssertionError:
    # frames are not equal
    pass
else:
    # frames are equal
    raise AssertionError
```

I am getting thhis key error even though i should be getting this assertion error that the try catch should be expecting.

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: test_input_1 = 'icd'
expected_outcome = DataFrame
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input_1, expected_outcome"
    def test_get_clinical_code_fail(test_input_1, expected_outcome):
        try:
            result = init_cohorts.get_clinical_code(test_input_1)
>           expected_outcome = init_cohorts.get_clinical_code(diag_config["clinical_input"]["prov_tbl"])

clinical_input = 'provider'
    def get_clinical_code(self, clinical_input):
>       tbl = self.cohorts_config.clinic_input[clinical_input]
E       KeyError: 'provider'

Comment: mainly the error says E       KeyError: 'provider' 
because when i do my working test for the code table value being 'ICD' and if i change that to prov, expecting it to fail i get 'provider; and the system is not handling it right